# Postgres or database_cleaner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, tinymce

I'm running into a very strange case. I have this scenario and sometimes it passes. Sometimes it doesn't. In fact, every step is green, but then after the step it produces this garbage stack trace which doesn't tell me anything about my app.

And I'm not doing anything sophisticated here, just simply trying to create a damn comment with TinyMCE. I have 20 other scenarios, some of which are much more complex.

It might help to state my environment all though it's pretty obvious from the stack trace:

Rails 3.1, ruby 1.9.2, latest "stable" version of everything. Postgres 9.0.4.

Could someone smarter than me explain why I get this issue?

```
Feature: Payment object comments
  In order to explain a action I performed on a payment object
  As a user
  I want to make a comment

  @wip @javascript
  Scenario: Creating a comment                         # features/payment_objects/comments.feature:8
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
    Given I am in a company                            # features/step_definitions/application_steps.rb:1
    And I have created 1 cash requisitions             # features/step_definitions/payment_steps.rb:5
    When I am on the requisitions page                 # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:44
    And I click on the 1st requisition                 # features/step_definitions/payment_steps.rb:39
    When I open the Comments tab                       # features/step_definitions/payment_steps.rb:101
http://127.0.0.1:51796/assets/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin.js?3.4.5:1 Error: Sprockets::EncodingError: /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/tinymce-rails-3.4.5/assets/precompiled/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
    When I fill in "comment_content" with "Testing123" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:64
    And I click on "Comment"                           # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:52
    Then there should be a comment saying "Testing123" # features/step_definitions/payment_steps.rb:106
http://127.0.0.1:51796/assets/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin.js?3.4.5:1 Error: Sprockets::EncodingError: /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/tinymce-rails-3.4.5/assets/precompiled/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
      NoMethodError: undefined method `nfields' for nil:NilClass:           SELECT tablename
                FROM pg_tables
                WHERE schemaname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
       (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:490:in `result_as_array'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:533:in `block in query'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:244:in `block in log'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:239:in `log'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:532:in `query'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:666:in `tables'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:455:in `disable_referential_integrity'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:113:in `each_table'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:106:in `clean'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:77:in `clean'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:56:in `block in clean'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:56:in `each'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/database_cleaner-0.6.7/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:56:in `clean'
      /Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/cucumber-rails-1.0.2/lib/cucumber/rails/hooks/database_cleaner.rb:9:in `After'
```

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar issue with the asset pipeline and tiny_mce when I would run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

...I tried converting the files editor_plugin_src.js and editor_plugin.js with iconv, etc, but ended up just deleting them for the time being, and everything worked.  I'm planning on "fixing it right," but if you don't need the spellchecker, you may not need these files...